# A normal space that is not regular, how is it possible?

Tags: general-topology

I can see on Math Stack that Sierpinski space is normal but not regular. Has is this possible ?

My definitions :

**Regular** $(X,T)$ is regular if for all $x\in X$ and all closed $A$ there are disjoint open $U$ and $V$ s.t. $x\in U$ and $A\subset V$.

**Normal** $(X,T)$ is normal if for all closed $A$ and $B$ there are disjoint open $U$ and $V$ s.t. $A\subset U$ and $B\subset V$.

So, how can Normal doesn't implies Regular ? By the way, in the Munkres (page 195) they say that : **"it's clear that a normal space is regular"**... apparently not that much since Sierpinski in a counter example... I don't understand anything, is Munkres wrong ?

By the way, it's clear that Regular implies Hausdorff, no ? (or Munkres failed an other time ?)

Comment: I think it's true if singleton are closed, what we call $T_1$ (normal $\implies $regular $\implies $ Hausdorff). Sierpinski is an example of space that is not $T_1$. After, I can't give you a counter example of a non $T_1$ space s.t. regular $\implies $ Hausdorff fail, but I know there are.

Comment: May be something as $S=\{x,y\}$ with the indiscrete topology. It's regular, since for all $x\in S$ there are no closed set that does not contain $x$ and thus regularity is obviously true, but is not Hausdorff...

Comment: Your definitions are not the same as Munkres's.

Comment: In any case, you have not given any explanation for why you believe that normal implies regular, besides just quoting Munkres.

Comment: In any case, the premise $x \notin A$ is missing in the definition of a regular space, and the premise $A \cap B = \varnothing$ is missing in the definition of a normal space. Then there is a difference in terminology. Some people define a regular space as one satisfying the $T_3$ separation axiom, others define it as a space satisfying $T_3$ and $T_0$ (which the users of the former convention call a $T_3$-space). Similarly for normal/$T_4$.

Comment: The people calling a space satisfying $T_3$ regular call a space satisfying $T_4$ normal, and those calling a $T_3 + T_0$ space regular call a space normal if it satisfies $T_4$ and $T_1$. "Normal implies regular" is true for the latter convention, but not for the former.

Answer (score 2):

Munkres assumed in regular and normal spaces both that one-point sets are closed (i.e. $X$ is $T_1$) this is only mentioned in the first sentence in the definition on p 195 (2nd edition):

> Suppose that one-point sets are closed in $X$. Then $X$ is said to be regular if for each pair consisting of a point $x$ and closed set $B$ disjoint from $x$, there exist disjoint open sets containing $x$ and $B$ respectively. The space $X$ is said to be normal if for each pair $A,B$ of disjoint closed sets of $X$ there exist disjoint open sets containing $A$ and $B$ respectively.

The next sentence after this definition is: "It's clear that regular spaces are Hausdorff, and that a normal space is regular".

This is indeed clear under the one-point set is closed extra condition: we can take singleton sets for the closed set in the regular case and get point separations, and we can take a singleton $A$ to get regular from normal.

Often a regular (in the more general sense you mean: separating points and *disjoint* closed sets) with closed singletons together is called $T_3$ and normal (separating *disjoint* closed sets) plus closed singletons is called $T_4$. We then get the chain of implications $T_4 \rightarrow T_3$ (as we saw) and  $T_3 \rightarrow T_2$ (where $T_2$ is Hausdorff) and $T_2 \rightarrow T_1$ ($T_1$ is that one-point sets are closed). Munkres doesn't really define $T_1$ or $T_0$ and does not really consider them.

With notions like normal and regular always check the definitions an author gives; usages vary and can be confusing.